# How can I limit the number of ManyToManyField in Django models?

Tags: django

I'm currently trying to implement some feature that users can track their recent visited stores in my website. To do that, I'm using `ManyToManyField` in Django models. Every time a user enters a detailed page of a store, the store object is stored in the user.

But, I wanna use a queue and store only 10 stores, so when a 11th store is stored, the earliest one is removed so that only 10 stores can be stored.

Is there a way to limit the number of `ManyToManyField` and remove the earliest one automatically?

Comment: Basically, there's no built-in function for that, but you can testify that with `if instance.fields.count() > 10` and to remove the earliest one, you will need to use an **Intermediary Model** in that `ManyToManyField`

Comment: @Lemayzeur I have a doubt, How can we remove the old one? (which implies, how can we sort m2m instances?)

Comment: You sort and remove the instances in the intermediate model (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)